# Locate and Copy a Text from an HTML Tag

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code:

```
<td class="label">Name:</td>
<td colspan="3">COHEN&nbsp;</td>
```

I would like to retrieve the text from this HTML `code==="COHEN"`.

I am working with Python Selenium and I need to put into a note this text but have no clue how can I select the text.

Thank you in advance,
Cohen

Comment: If you save the `driver.page_source` from your selenium webdriver object, you can then parse through that html with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Show what have you tried already

Answer (score 0):

So in selenium there are webElements. WebElements have the attribute text, which is the visible text inside the element. 
So all you need to to is find the WebElement and then get the attribute from it. If you are using xpaths it would look like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@colspan='3']")
visibleText = element.text
```

Of course I imagine that you might have an issue with finding the xpath like this because I imagine that you will have more then 1 td tag, with colspans that are 3. But once you find the right element, getting the text from it is simple enough.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff! i did as per your post and i got this: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. My code is like this. I am tryng to retrieve the text to put it into a comment like this: compania=browser.find_element(By.XPATH("//td[@colspan='3']"))

textcompania=compania.text
note.send_keys(“My text—“ +textcompania +  "Cleared")

Comment: Hmm. can you guarantee that your browser.find_element is only returning just 1 element? I think that might be the first thing to check. If "//td[@colspan='3']" is a path that return more then 1 element, or does not return an element, when used with find_element then I imagine that is the issue. I also made the mistake of going the java selenium for most of my answer, as it looks like you noticed I will update my answer to be python and not java.  But you may want to try something like `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@colspan='3'])` or `broswer.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@colspan='3']")`.

Comment: thank you @Jeff!!! yes you are right! i got this error TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I tried first with xpath, and when i inserted the xpath into the note i inserted a very big url. I think that this is why i got the error, cos dynamically behind the text there is an url that retrieves the text from other servers. Is there a different why I could solve this issue?

Comment: I have edited and the class of the element in the original post.

Comment: So just to make sure that I understand correctly. Are you saying that the text that is inside the td tag, that you are trying to get from your web page, is being retrieved from another server? And that when you try to get the text from inside the td, instead you are getting the url that is used to get that text?

Comment: yes Jeff! you are right! i saw this while using the xpath to locate the element/thetext from that part of the page.

Comment: Well I am surprised a little that it gave you the url rather then the text that is visible. I can think of a couple of possible solutions. The first may or may not work, but would be the easiest to implement. Try having your program wait just before getting the text. The wait time probably doesn't have to be to long, just long enough for the web page to get the result from the url. The other possible solution, is to make a call to the url that you get from the element, and just store the result from that url.